# jQuery Ajax request works in http but fails over https (error 404)

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, codeigniter, https

I got a LAMP testing server (Apache 2.4.25) and in order to test http2 I have configured SSL with a self signed certificate. Everything works except jQuery Ajax requests which works perfectly over http, but now over https it returns an error 404.

The PHP framework is codeIgniter behind.

Could it be the self signed certificate which cause the problem?
Is it considered as a cross domain request?

here is the ajax code

```
//récup initiale des infos du panier de sélection
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'ajax_selection/getNumItems/',
        type: 'POST',
        // csrf protection
        data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'},
        datatype: 'json',
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                alert("Problème de connexion : Vérifiez votre connexion internet");
            } else {
                throw "errorThrown : " + errorThrown + " | textStatus : " + textStatus + " | Error : AjaxContent has not a valid path";
            }
        },
        success: function (data, jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // notification de l'ajout à la liste de sélection
            //console.log('selected Item '+data);//test ok
            $('.link-selection').html(data);
        }
    });
```

How can I deal with this problem?

Thank you for your help

[edit]
here is the htaccess

```
#   Toutes les autres URL vont être redirigées vers le fichier index.php.
#RewriteRule blog$ wp/index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Redirection permanente des pages formation-motcle-annee vers /formation/motcle/annee
RewriteRule ^formations-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+).html  /formations/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^formations-([a-z]+).html  /formations/$1/$2 [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, i Found the problem it was related to the apache conf, I missed the directive

```
AllowOverride All
```

in the  section, sorry & thanks for your help !

Comment: 505 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (your website url)
```

It worked for me, i hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this in the virtualHost conf : Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your ajax code so that i can help you?

Comment: Please check your JavaScript console when you call this request from browser, it should show you which non-SSL links are causing it to break.

Comment: like this : The page at https://<your site> displayed insecure content from http://<remote site>

Comment: yes, try to load this with ssl like :  https://fonts.googleapi/ instead of http://fonts.googleapi/

Comment: nope it doesn't work despite all resources are loaded over https, I don't understand why I got a 404 over ssl and is working over http

Comment: I think that it's better related to the htaccess configuration, I'm investigating on this...